# Error: 'Can not get property 'replace' of undefined reference or null' only on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, animation, spritely

I'm trying to implement a simple animation using Jquery Spritely.
The problem is that on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari everything works fine.
But on IE I got the follow error: 
 'Can not get property 'replace' of undefined reference or null'

The fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/74KgX/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="citybackground"></div>

    <div id="cityclouds"></div>

     <div id="motoboy"></div>
</div>



 $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#citybackground').pan({ fps:30, speed: 3, dir: 'left' });
                $('#cityclouds').pan({ fps: 30, speed: 2, dir: 'right' });
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing the "background" CSS property must be broken for IE10.

```
repeat-x bottom; / BROKEN */
repeat-x 100px 10px; /* WORKS */
```

**edit** If you use bottom you may want to specify the background-position and/or background-attachment properties separately in the css.